# No top bar on windows when maximized on Ubuntu Netbook with Dekstop session

Tags: 10.10, gnome-classic

I have Ubuntu Netbook Edition 10.10 installed but I found Unity to be too slow. I've tried switching to the Desktop session when logging in but now when my windows are maximize, there are no windows top bar. How can I get back my top bar?

Executing metacity --replace didn't do anything by the way. A screenshot to show the problem:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should remove `maximus`, or at least make sure it doesn't get run anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The netbook edition uses a small utility called `maximus` to maximize applications as default, and to remove the decoration on windows, to save screen space.

To get the standard desktop behaviour, open the session editor (From **System -> Preferences -> Startup applications**. Locate Maximus in the list, and uncheck it. (It might be called "Automaximize" or something like that in the list.)

Log out, and log in again (or execute `pkill maximus` in a terminal).